# Woo Commerce using WP_Query to get products that match price range, with an additional required product attribute

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I have code that successfully returns product within a price range. However, I need to also filter by a product attribute called 'size'.

So I should get all products of a certain size between the given price range.

My code works for the price range part, but I can't work out the correct way to add the size part.

Here's my code:

```
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            array(
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => $_POST['product_price_min'],
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => $_POST['product_price_max'],
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            )

        ),
        array(
            array(
                            'taxonomy'        => 'pa_size',
                            'field'           => 'slug',
                            'terms'           =>  $_POST['size'],
                            'operator'        => 'IN',

            )
        )
    )
);


$products = new WP_Query($params);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688846/wp-query-woocommerce-filter-variable-products-by-attributes-and-variations-regul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mixing up your [meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) and [tax query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).  try this:

```
$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => $_POST['product_price_min'],
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => $_POST['product_price_max'],
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy'        => 'pa_size',
        'field'           => 'slug',
        'terms'           =>  $_POST['size'],
        'operator'        => 'IN',
        )
    )
);


$products = new WP_Query($params);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!